# Is there a Revert command of Git in Vs 2019?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

There is a *Revert* command of Git in Android Studio 3.5.3, you can see Image 1. So I can use this command to give up all modification.

But I can't the *Revert* command  in Vs 2019, I have installed Git Extensions, you can see Image 2.

How can I give up all modification in Vs 2019  when I use GitHub ?

**Image 1**
[image]

**Image 2**
[image]

**Image 3**
[image]

Comment: `revert` is pretty rarely used so why not just use the CLI for it? Or use the CLI for everything. ;) ...Or try GitKraken or GitAhead (GUI based clients).

Comment: Gitextensions integration inside VS don't bring all the features of Gitextensions in VS. Choose 'Browse', that opens the mai  window of Gitextensions where you will be able to do everything you want with Git.

Comment: Thanks! To  Philippe, I still can't find Revert Command by your way, you can see Image 3.

Answer (score 4):

I did some reading about what the 'revert' button in Android Studio accomplishes, and it seems to me this is not a 'Git' Revert: it rolls back all the local changes that have not yet been committed. 
In Visual Studio there are two variants of this (none of which needs the Git Extensions):

- to roll back changes in a document that has changes: right click and
  select 'source control' - 'Undo'

[image]

- to roll back all changes in your project: in the 'Changes' Window, right click on the 'root' folder of the project  and select 'Undo changes...'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your menu is done on the most recent commit, where you see "`Undo last commit`"

Check if "Revert" is visible when you trigger the same contextual menu on a commit which is not the last one.

Comment: Thanks!  but `Undo last commit ` can't do that

Comment: @HelloCW I was not talking about "undo last commit", I was talking about "Revert". But if you cannot use also "Revert this commit", then... I am not sure if what you need is available.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get all the changes and revert to the previous commit,

`git log`, get the commit id of the commit you wish to get.
`git fetch origin <CommitId>` will get the commit changes.
`git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD` will apply the changes to your local repository and at the backend its `revert` which actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'Revert' using the built in client: 'Changes' -  'Actions' - 'View history' ... Right click on specific commit and select 'Revert' in context menu:

[image]

You can Revert in the Git Extensions Window from the context menu (by right clicking, not via the command menu) for any commit:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  but I can't use `Revert this commit` to give up all modification just like the `Revert` operation in Android Studio.